# Minimizing the maximum distance in a graph

Tags: algorithm, graph, nodes, graph-theory, edge-list

Let's say we have a weighted undirected graph. Assume there are N nodes(cities) in the graph and we want to build M (M<=N) hospitals in the city. Now we need to choose the most optimal solution, such that the maximum distance from a city to a city that has a hospital will be minimized.

Let's say we have a 3 cities and we need to build 1 hospital. Let there be edges 1-3 and 2-3, with weights 83 and 71 respectively. Obviously the optimal solution is to build a hospital in city 3, since then the maximum distance would be 83.

My idea was to use the Floyd-Warshall Algorithm and then build a hospital in a city that has a minimal max value in the distance array. Then update another array b such that b1 shows the minimum distance from city 1 to a city that has hospital and define bi simularly. After that I want to update the distance value like this:

```
dist_i_j = min (dist_i_j, b_j)
```

And repeat this until we have build all M hospitals.

But there are some cases for which this algorithm runs into a problem. Let's say we're given this graph and we need to build 3 hospitals:

```
edge 1-2 with distance 1
edge 1-3 with distance 2
edge 2-4 with distance 7
edge 2-6 with distance 3
edge 3-4 with distance 5
edge 4-5 with distance 2
edge 5-6 with distance 4
```

After the Floyd-Warshall algorithm the distance table will look like:

```
0 1 2 7 8 4
1 0 3 7 7 3
2 3 0 5 7 6
7 7 5 0 2 6
8 7 7 2 0 4
4 3 6 6 4 0
```

Obviously now it's best to build a hospital in city 6, since the max value would be 6. Now update the values:

```
0 1 2 6 4 0
1 0 3 6 4 0
2 3 0 5 4 0
4 3 5 0 2 0
4 3 6 2 0 0
4 3 6 6 4 0
```

But know we don't know whether to build a hospital in city 3 or in city 4. If we build a hospital in city 4, then updating the table we would get that we need to build hospital in city 1 and the maximum distance will be 2.

But if we build a hospital in city 3 and update the values we would get that it's best to build a hospital in city 4 or in city 5. But in both cases the max value would be 3. So how do I overcome this problem?

Comment: You may want to look at centrality indices, specifically [betweenness centrality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Betweenness_centrality) might meet your needs. There is a whole bunch of other centrality measures with differing degrees of complexity and applicability to your problem. If it is any use to you, [here](http://wwwmayr.informatik.tu-muenchen.de/lehre/2012WS/anga/slides/ANGA.pdf) is a set of German slides (I don't think they are available in English), and [here](http://wwwmayr.informatik.tu-muenchen.de/lehre/2012WS/anga/index.html.de) is the course site with references.

Answer (score 4):

This is the k-center problem and is known to be NP-hard. If the graph satisfies triangle inequality, then there is a 2-approximation algorithm. See http://algo2.iti.kit.edu/vanstee/courses/kcenter.pdf